# How can I install pymc3?

Tags: python, spyder, modulenotfounderror, pymc3

I have installed pymc3 via conda. conda create -n pm3env -c conda-forge "python=3.8" libpython mkl-service m2w64-toolchain numba python-graphviz scipy

However, when I tried it in Spyder I got the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymc3'"

I've uninstalled anaconda, and used the pymc3 installation protocole from https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/4937

Comment: _I have installed pymc3 via conda_ Please show the actual command you used to install pymc3.  The command you showed creates a _virtual environment_, but it does not actually install the package.

Comment: Thanks John, 
I've used pip install pymc3

Comment: Now show the output of this command `pip show pymc3`, specifically the `Location` line.  Also show the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: From pip show pymc3, I got
Location: C:\Users\Leveneur\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

From import sys
['C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3', '', 'C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Leveneur\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Comment: That code shows that `C:\Users\Leveneur\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` is on your module import path, so I don't understand why the module is not found.  Did you run this code the exact same way as the failed `import pymp3` code?

Comment: Dear John 
Thanks for your help, I've reinstalled anaconda. 
I've created an environment to install pymc3
Apparently, I've an issue between numpy and pymc3. This what I got on spyder

Comment: import pymc3
....
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) on how to use packages from a different environment. I think that will solve your problem.